# splitting dictionary and writing it to different csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, split

I want to split the python dictionary and write it to different files based on NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE and size of dictionary

Input

```
NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE
```

so if NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE = 2 and size of dictionary is 10 the i want the dictionary to be splitted into 5 files(each file will have 2 rows)

Script

```
import csv
NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE = 2
s = {"2222":["1","2","3"],"3456":["2","3","4"],"5634":["4","5"],"23543":["456","3"],"29587":["4","5"],"244":["23","34"],"455":["3","4"],"244221":["5"],"23232345":["2323","43"]}

def again(c,h,NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE1):
    f3 = open('num_'+str(h)+'.csv', 'at')
    if c == 1:
        ceh = 2
    else:
        ceh = c
    print ceh
    v = 0
    for w in s:
        v = v + 1
        if v < ceh:
            pass
        elif v > NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE1:
            print "yes"
            NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE1 = NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE1 + 1
            h = NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE1 + 1
            again(c,h,NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE1)
        else:
            writer = csv.writer(f3,delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            writer.writerow(s[w])

        c = c + 1

def split():
    f3 = open('has_'+str(NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE)+'.csv', 'at')
    writer = csv.writer(f3,delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    c = 0
    for w in s:

        if c >= NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE:

            NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE1 = NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE + 1
            h = NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE
            again(c,h,NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE1)
            break
        else:
            #print NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE
            writer = csv.writer(f3,delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

            writer.writerow(s[w])

        c = c + 1

split()
```

But this script is not working and creates many files

In the above script NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE = 2 and size of dictionary s is 9

so i want 5 files first four file will contain 2 rows each and fifth file will contain 1 row

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: It would help if you could show the expected contents of the files base on your input.

Comment: expected content: i want value for a key (["1","2","3"]) to be written in csv file...

Comment: So you want a single file to exist with `(["1","2","3"])` in it? That's what you just said, but that seems very different than what you described in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my method is flat the dict first, then split flat dict to sub list with length you want

```
    import csv
    flatDict = [ i  for i in s.items()]
    splitFlatDict = [flatDict[i:i+NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE] for i in xrange(0,len(flatDict),NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE)]
    for i,rows in enumerate(splitFlatDict):
      with open(str(i) + '.csv','wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(rows)
```